# How can I access enum value with a string in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, enums, google-calendar-api

So, I am currently working on a project where I collect the data from a google form and then create event(s) in the google calendar based on the response. I am using Google Apps Script for this purpose. My form lets the user input one or more weekdays in which they want the event to occur.

But weekdays are stored in an enum. Here's the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/weekday.html) to the documentation.

This is how one can create a recurring event every Wednesday at a given time between specified dates.

```
CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEventSeries(event_name,start_date,
CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()
           .onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY)
           .until(end_date));
```

Now, I am having a list of weekdays with me like `['Monday', 'Wednesday']`. This is stored in an object called `data`. Here is my approach for creating events using such a list:

```
 for(var i=0;i<data["Weekdays"].length;++i)
{
    var day = data["Weekdays"][i].toUpperCase();
    CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEventSeries(data["SubjectName"],new Date(start_date),
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()         
               .onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday[day])                     
               .until(end_date));
}
```

I am new to web development yet and have never worked with enums before. I apologize in advance for any mistakes or uncertainty in my question.

Comment: I did a Logger.log(CalendarApp.WeekDay['FRIDAY']) and it returns the same thing as CalendarApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY  so perhaps that will work just use SUNDAY through SATTURDAY for your inputs.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! I just found out that the mistake was in the last line( the until(end_date) part :(. But Thank you for your help and time. I will delete this question after I confirm that you have seen my reply.

Answer (score 0):

In addition with Cooper's comment.

By using for loop, you are calling the API multiple times. Instead, use [onlyOnWeekdays(days)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/recurrence-rule#onlyonweekdaysdays)

Example:

```
var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence()
    .addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekdays(
        [CalendarApp.Weekday.TUESDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.THURSDAY]);
```

In your code:

```
for(var i=0;i<data["Weekdays"].length;++i)
{
    var day = data["Weekdays"][i].toUpperCase();
    CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEventSeries(data["SubjectName"],new Date(start_date),
    CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule()         
               .onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.MONDAY, CalendarApp.Weekday.WEDNESDAY])                    
               .until(end_date));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and efforts, but I was concerned about how to access weekdays using a string. I found out that the mistake was in the until(end_date) part. I apologize for the inconvenience caused.